# Objects with recursive properties in php

Tags: php, oop, recursion

I'm using a class, `moduleSelectQuery`, to generate SQL queries in PHP.

Basically, this class breaks up the individual components of a SQL SELECT query, such as the table name, the fields to select, the WHERE conditions, etc.

However, this quickly becomes complicated with nested queries, such as an `WHERE table1.field1 IN (SELECT table2.field2 from table2 WHERE table2.field3 = criteria)`

Currently I have a property for `moduleSelectQuery` called `$inWhereClause` that is used to store the `WHERE... IN(SELECT...)` clause. Like the other properties (i.e. `$tableName, $whereClause, $havingClause`), this is parsed together by its own function based on user input.

However, this parsing function is fundamentally limited. Even if I devote enough effort to it as I do parsing the `$whereClause` property, it can't have additional nested select statements.

I think one way to do this would be to set `$inWhereClause` to be another `moduleSelectQuery` object. This would mean that the parent `moduleSelectQuery` would have a property which was itself a `moduleSelectQuery`, i.e. it would be a recursive object. Is this possible/good practice in PHP? Are there other drawbacks?

Comment: extended child object of parent?  Perhaps change it so you have an objcet that creates a select statement as a child of a parent object which creates the "final" statement so you would call the child multiple times  to create the primary select and the sub select and then they're merged back together in the primary object.  Perhaps a statement template could be used along with some form of factory to build the query.  I'm just spouting ideas ofc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could see this being a possible solution. Visualize having a Person class. A person might have a child, which is a person. Doesn't seem unreasonable.

I wouldn't necessarily call this a recursive object, as the object doesn't reference itself, but rather that an object can have a property that is an instance of the same class.

It would, obviously need to be nested appropriately, as only sub-queries in the Where statement would need to be moduleSelectQuery object, where simple comparisons would be instances of strings, or integers.

The only drawbacks that can arrive from this approach are in the design of the class, and methods. I do not see any glaring performance issues, or maintainability issues.